# Failed To Get Class Reference from Native code invoking Java Code

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

I'm new to Java Programming. I'm trying to call Java API's from Native C++ code using JNI. I'm getting the following error
"Failed To Get Class Reference"
Below is the code snippet
Java Side:

```
package com.example.playaudio;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
        private MediaPlayer mp;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
                setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                Button button1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button_1);
                Button button2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button_2);
                button1.setOnClickListener(this);
                button2.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        public void onClick(View v) {
                int resId;
                switch (v.getId()) {
                case R.id.button_1:
                        resId = R.raw.a;
                        break;
                case R.id.button_2:
                        resId = R.raw.b;
                        break;
                default:
                        resId = R.raw.a;
                        break;
                }
                // Release any resources from previous MediaPlayer
                if (mp != null) {
                        mp.release();
                }
                // Create a new MediaPlayer to play this sound
                mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, resId);
                mp.start();
        }
        public void onStart() {
                int resId;
                // Release any resources from previous MediaPlayer
                if (mp != null) {
                        mp.release();
                }
                resId = R.raw.b;
                // Create a new MediaPlayer to play this sound
                mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, resId);
                mp.start();
        }
}
```

Native Side(C++ with JNI):

```
JavaVM * create_vm() {
    JavaVM   *jvm;
    JNIEnv  *env;

    JavaVMInitArgs vm_args;
    JavaVMOption *options   = new JavaVMOption[1];
    options[0].optionString = "-Djava.class.path=.";

    vm_args.version  = JNI_VERSION_1_6;
    vm_args.nOptions = 1;
    vm_args.options  = options;
    vm_args.ignoreUnrecognized = false;

    // Load and Initailize JVM, returns an JNI Intterface
    int ret = JNI_CreateJavaVM(&jvm, (void**)&env, &vm_args);
    if (ret < 0 )
            printf("Unable to launch JVM \n");

    return jvm;
}

void PlayAudio()
{
    int status;
    bool isAttached = false;
    JNIEnv *env;


    printf("PlayAudio\n");
    status = gJavaVM->GetEnv((void **) &env, JNI_VERSION_1_6);


    status = gJavaVM->AttachCurrentThread((void **)&env, NULL);


    jclass interfaceClass =
            env->FindClass("com/example/playaudio/MainActivity");
    if(!interfaceClass) {
            printf("PlayAudio: Failed To Get Class Reference\n");
            return;
    }

    jmethodID altmethod = env->GetMethodID(interfaceClass, "<init>","()V");
    jobject obj = env->NewGlobalRef(env->NewObject(interfaceClass, altmethod));

    jmethodID method = env->GetMethodID(interfaceClass, "onStart", "(I)V");
    if(!method)
    {
            printf("PlayAudio: Failed To Get Object Method\n");
            return;
    }
    env->CallVoidMethod(obj, method, NULL);
}
```

Please correct me if anything is wrong in my coding.Following is the error

PlayAudio

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/example/playaudio/MainActivity
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.playaudio.MainActivity
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
PlayAudio: Failed To Get Class Reference
```

Best Regards
Kumar

Comment: Please post the full error message, instead of your summary of the message.

Comment: The following statement is executed printf("PlayAudio: Failed To Get Class Reference\n")

Comment: @kumar When you get an error condition in JNI, or indeed anywhere, you should print all the information that is available, rather than just making up your own error message. All that does is tell you an error occurred. There are several JNI functions concerning exceptions and stack traces. Use them. Post the result here. Edit them into your question.

Comment: I said to edit them into your question. Don't post code or exceptions as comments. You can see for yourself that they are illegible.

Comment: Hi I have added the error in the question itself

Answer (score 0):

Put your find class code in the JNI_OnLoad and see if it works.  If it does, your having an issue with the java class loader.  If it does not, you botched your java class path when running the application.

```
jint JNI_OnLoad(JavaVM* vm, void* reserved) {
  jclass interfaceClass = env->FindClass("com/example/playaudio/MainActivity");
  if(!interfaceClass) {
    printf("PlayAudio: Failed To Get Class Reference\n");
  }
```

If your problem is the class loader, it might be due to JNLP...  I haven't looked into exactly why the problem exists but I suspect its related to a class loader that has additional security that's not being addressed.  This is all speculative at this point so please run the test above and let us know what happens.

Comment: Hi Alex, Thanks for your reply. The proposed solution is not working.My class path is bin/classes/com/example/playaudio/. Accordingly i modified the code, still no success.Iam trying to call aandroid related jaava clesses. Please suggest me if you have any alternate methods.

Answer (score 0):

you can try first step is give the fix path to your Java class on option value:
options[0].optionString = "-Djava.class.path=."; ==> Set full path your Java library instead
If it does NOT work, i have doubt about steps you expose Java method to your native library. Please double check whether or not you compiled java class into class file in order that native library can make a reference to it.