# Android and Native C/C++ Calling

Tags: android, java-native-interface, media-player

Is there anyway to call android media player JAVA API's to call from Native C/C++ ?
If does not, how can we achieve this. Im new to Android.Please help.

Best Regards,
Kumar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These links might be useful to you,
[calling from jni audio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2560748/how-do-i-handle-calls-to-audiotrack-from-jni-without-crashing?rq=1), [calling java from c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5198105/calling-a-java-method-from-c-in-android?rq=1), [calling java memeber](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7268450/calling-java-class-member-from-native-c-c-code).

Tutorial on developing media application using NDK ,

[Tutorial on media apps NDK](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBsQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.packtpub.com%2Fsites%2Fdefault%2Ffiles%2Fdownloads%2FDeveloping_Multimedia_Applications_with_NDK.pdf&ei=ZpeyU7GUJsqMuAT36YKgAw&usg=AFQjCNGCqIPW31Rz65EFSp4ySB3kCErsqg&bvm=bv.69837884,d.c2E&cad=rja)

Comment: Please share if you have any sample code. I followed the procedure still its confusing.

Comment: @kumar have checked the tutorial ? calling media application is similar to what is done for audio

Comment: I did the similar programming for playing audio. But im getting the error while loading class reference. please peruse the url http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24490020/failed-to-get-class-reference-from-native-code-invoking-java-code